# Function App stopped working with a SocketException

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions

I have an Azure Function App with the following function:

```
    [FunctionName(nameof(LeaveGroup))]
    public static async Task LeaveGroup([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "post", Route = "LeaveGroup/{userId}")] HttpRequest req,
        string userId,
        [SignalR(HubName = "webrtchub")] IAsyncCollector<SignalRGroupAction> signalRGroupActions,
        ILogger log)
    {
        await signalRGroupActions.AddAsync(
            new SignalRGroupAction
            {
                UserId = userId,
                Action = GroupAction.RemoveAll
            });
        log.LogInformation($"Trigger function removed {userId} from all groups");
    }
```

This function is called from a Xamarin.Forms app installed on mobile phones. It used to work, but recently it just stopped working, with this exception:

> 2021-07-19T18:09:42.739 [Error] Executed 'LeaveGroup' (Failed, Id=176fbb5a-05d0-44ec-95f4-4e5766f1e694, Duration=100020ms)System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException : The operation was canceled. ---> System.IO.IOException : Unable to read data from the transport connection: The I/O operation has been aborted because of either a thread exit or an application request.. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException : The I/O operation has been aborted because of either a thread exit or an application request.End of inner exceptionat System.Net.Sockets.Socket.AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs.ThrowException(SocketError error,CancellationToken cancellationToken)at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs.GetResult(Int16 token)at async System.Net.Security.SslStream.g__InternalFillBufferAsync|215_0TReadAdapterat System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()at async System.Net.Security.SslStream.ReadAsyncInternal[TReadAdapter](TReadAdapter adapter,Memory`1 buffer)at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()at async System.Net.Security.SslStream.ReadAsyncInternal[TReadAdapter](TReadAdapter adapter,Memory`1 buffer)at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()at async System.Net.Http.HttpConnection.FillAsync()at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()at async System.Net.Http.HttpConnection.ReadNextResponseHeaderLineAsync(Boolean foldedHeadersAllowed)at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()at async System.Net.Http.HttpConnection.SendAsyncCore(HttpRequestMessage request,CancellationToken cancellationToken)End of inner exceptionat async System.Net.Http.HttpConnection.SendAsyncCore(HttpRequestMessage request,CancellationToken cancellationToken)at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()at async System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithNtConnectionAuthAsync(HttpConnection connection,HttpRequestMessage request,Boolean doRequestAuth,CancellationToken cancellationToken)at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()at async System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithRetryAsync(HttpRequestMessage request,Boolean doRequestAuth,CancellationToken cancellationToken)at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()at async System.Net.Http.RedirectHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request,CancellationToken cancellationToken)at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()at async System.Net.Http.DiagnosticsHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request,CancellationToken cancellationToken)at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()at async Microsoft.Extensions.Http.Logging.LoggingHttpMessageHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request,CancellationToken cancellationToken)at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()at async Microsoft.Extensions.Http.Logging.LoggingScopeHttpMessageHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request,CancellationToken cancellationToken)at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()at async System.Net.Http.HttpClient.FinishSendAsyncUnbuffered(Task`1 sendTask,HttpRequestMessage request,CancellationTokenSource cts,Boolean disposeCts)at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()at async Microsoft.Azure.SignalR.Management.RestHubLifetimeManager.CallRestApiAsync(HttpRequestMessage request,CancellationToken cancellationToken)at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()at async Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.SignalRService.AzureSignalRClient.RemoveUserFromAllGroups(String userId)at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()at async Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.SignalRService.SignalRAsyncCollector`1.AddAsync[T](T item,CancellationToken cancellationToken)at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()at async LATICRETE_WebRTC.SignallingFunction.webrtchub.LeaveGroup(HttpRequest req,String userId,IAsyncCollector`1 signalRGroupActions,ILogger log) at D:\a\1\s\LATICRETE_WebRTC.SignallingFunction\WebRTCHub.cs : 60at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()at async Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.VoidTaskMethodInvoker`2.InvokeAsync[TReflected,TReturnType](TReflected instance,Object[] arguments) at C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Executors\VoidTaskMethodInvoker.cs : 20at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()at async Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionInvoker`2.InvokeAsync[TReflected,TReturnValue](Object instance,Object[] arguments) at C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Executors\FunctionInvoker.cs : 52at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()at async Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor.InvokeWithTimeoutAsync(IFunctionInvoker invoker,ParameterHelper parameterHelper,CancellationTokenSource timeoutTokenSource,CancellationTokenSource functionCancellationTokenSource,Boolean throwOnTimeout,TimeSpan timerInterval,IFunctionInstance instance) at C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Executors\FunctionExecutor.cs : 555at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()at async Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor.ExecuteWithWatchersAsync(IFunctionInstanceEx instance,ParameterHelper parameterHelper,ILogger logger,CancellationTokenSource functionCancellationTokenSource) at C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Executors\FunctionExecutor.cs : 501at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()at async Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor.ExecuteWithLoggingAsync(IFunctionInstanceEx instance,FunctionStartedMessage message,FunctionInstanceLogEntry instanceLogEntry,ParameterHelper parameterHelper,ILogger logger,CancellationToken cancellationToken) at C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Executors\FunctionExecutor.cs : 279at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()at async Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor.ExecuteWithLoggingAsync(IFunctionInstanceEx instance,FunctionStartedMessage message,FunctionInstanceLogEntry instanceLogEntry,ParameterHelper parameterHelper,ILogger logger,CancellationToken cancellationToken) at C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Executors\FunctionExecutor.cs : 326at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()at async Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor.TryExecuteAsync(IFunctionInstance functionInstance,CancellationToken cancellationToken) at C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Executors\FunctionExecutor.cs : 94
> 2021-07-19T18:09:52.073 [Information] Host Status: {"id": "laticretewebrtcsignallingfunctio","state": "Running","version": "3.0.15733.0","versionDetails": "3.0.15733 Commit hash: a0b4f7d3a2fadb61bc3e0ef99987e1701f12e310","platformVersion": "94.0.7.89","instanceId": "a5417f0abc2a3720d9355e90ddea6acefbf6ad127e773ccfa4ddc4c1fff74660","computerName": "RD0003FF465049","processUptime": 759643}
> 2021-07-19T18:09:52.075 [Information] Host Status: {"id": "laticretewebrtcsignallingfunctio","state": "Running","version": "3.0.15733.0","versionDetails": "3.0.15733 Commit hash: a0b4f7d3a2fadb61bc3e0ef99987e1701f12e310","platformVersion": "94.0.7.89","instanceId": "a5417f0abc2a3720d9355e90ddea6acefbf6ad127e773ccfa4ddc4c1fff74660","computerName": "RD0003FF465049","processUptime": 759645}

It seems like the problem happened at signalRGroupActions.AddAsync() call.

This does not happen when the function is called from an iPhone, but does happen when called from an Android phone or Android emulator.

What could cause this issue, and how can I fix it?

ADDED: Suddenly it just works again. This is scary, as it can happen any time, and I still don't know the root cause...

Comment: Seems like it times out based on the time of 100020ms?

Comment: @misha130 But the time out probably just shows that there is a real issue that causes it, right?

Comment: @misha130 Added to my original question.

Comment: are you on a consumption plan or an app plan?

Comment: @misha130 probably consumption, but can this be an issue, if if works right now?

Comment: Yea, I am just saying maybe switch over to having an app behind it instead of serverless (from consumption -> app plan). It will 100% fix your issue since your server won't go up and down anymore